# loading external json,tsv and csv file on jsfiddle

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, jsfiddle

I am working on the d3.js project in which I need to load json, tsv and csv files. I want to upload all the files on jsfiddle. In jsfiddle you have sections for html, css and javascript. But I am not sure how to load external json, csv and tsv file so that my D3 map can read it. I tried using [[How to add local json file in jsfiddle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911126/how-to-add-local-json-file-in-jsfiddle][1]) but I am getting error as:

"jquery-1.11.0.js:9666 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.dropbox.com/s/n4anyoro797w2kq/test.json?dl=0. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405."

Where I am getting wrong? Any other approach for this?