# How to import json file from my computer to jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsfiddle

I have a task to complete a task through js fiddle, my task is using json data. My question is how to import my json file from my computer to js fiddle ?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911126/how-to-add-local-json-file-in-jsfiddle

Comment: I have try it, but the result always show error alert,

Comment: Thanks anyway, anyone who want to see the example of working with json data in jsfiddle can visit my last work https://jsfiddle.net/zx0j7tsd/

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the json file, simply add the json content inside the js part in a variable.